# I/O in ruby script

Tags: ruby

I am was writing a small script in ruby and it looks like this:

```
f_id = XXXX
lane = 1-8
s_id = XXX

puts Flow.find_by_id(f_id).lanes[lane - 1].mixes.select {|m| m 
if m.sample_id == s_id}[0].pipe_result.gb.name
```

I am calling this test.rb

what I would like to do, is instead of giving the inputs inside the script, I should be able to give it from outside.

something like this:

```
./test.rb 123 6 sdef
```

How can I give this small modification to this script.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the constant `ARGV` that gives access to the arguments passed to your script. Have a look at the "Command line arguments" section [here](http://zetcode.com/lang/rubytutorial/basics/).

Comment: How about an example, please.

Comment: @Angelo: How about some googling?

Comment: @Angelo I have added a link that you may find helpful